# Multi row data consolidate to single row

Tags: sql, pivot

I am trying to consolidate multi row data to a single row and then union to another table. But unfortunately, I failed with the multi row consolidation. I tried the Pivot option found on the site, but being a novice I failed on that.

My multi row data table looks like this -
[image: current table]

I like to create the table like the one below -
[image: future table]

after this, I like to inner join another table with this based on ID. 
Not sure how to write the pivot or another formula for it.

Please show me some light on it --

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which DBMS you are using, but here is a solution for SQL Server using T-SQL. I solved this by using dynamic sql.

**1. Create source data**

Please next time, don't add an image with your data but type it, it is easier to copy.

```
CREATE TABLE DataSource (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(255), Details VARCHAR(255), Time_In VARCHAR(255), Time_Out VARCHAR(255), Value VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO DataSource VALUES
(1, 'a', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '1'),
(1, 'b', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '2'),
(1, 'c', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '3'),
(2, 'b', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '4'),
(3, 'a', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '1'),
(3, 'b', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '2'),
(3, 'c', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '3'),
(3, 'd', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '4'),
(4, 'b', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '1'),
(4, 'd', 'string', DATEADD(HOUR, -1, GETDATE()), GETDATE(), '2')
```

**2. Get names and columnnames**

In the table @ColumnsPerName you manually add columns which should be taken into account for your final result.

```
DECLARE @Names TABLE (Name VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @Names SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM DataSource

DECLARE @ColumnsPerName TABLE (ColName VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @ColumnsPerName VALUES ('Details'),('Time_In'),('Time_Out'),('Value')
```

**3. Get pivot columnnames**

```
CREATE TABLE #PivotColumns (Name VARCHAR(255), ColName VARCHAR(255), PivotHeader VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #PivotColumns 
SELECT Name, ColName, Name + ' ' + ColName FROM @Names CROSS JOIN @ColumnsPerName
```

**4. Create pivot source table**

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @sql = ''
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(255), @colname VARCHAR(255), @pivotHeader VARCHAR(255)
DECLARE mCursor CURSOR FOR SELECT Name, ColName, PivotHeader FROM #PivotColumns
OPEN mCursor FETCH NEXT FROM mCursor
    INTO @name, @colname, @pivotHeader
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @Sql += 'SELECT ID, ''' + @pivotHeader + ''' AS col, ' + @colname 
        + ' AS val FROM DataSource WHERE Name = ''' + @name + ''' UNION ALL '
    FETCH NEXT FROM mCursor INTO @name, @colname, @pivotHeader
END
CLOSE mCursor
DEALLOCATE mCursor

SET @Sql = LEFT(@Sql, LEN(@SQL) - 10) --remove last UNION ALL

CREATE TABLE #PivotSource (ID INT, PivotHeader VARCHAR(255), PivotValue VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO #PivotSource 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

**5. Get result**

```
DECLARE @pivotHeaders VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @pivotHeaders = COALESCE(@pivotHeaders + ', ', '') + '[' + PivotHeader + ']' FROM #PivotColumns

DECLARE @pSql NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @pSql = 'SELECT ID, ' + @pivotHeaders + ' FROM (SELECT s.ID, c.PivotHeader, s.PivotValue FROM #PivotColumns AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN #PivotSource AS s ON s.PivotHeader = c.PivotHeader) AS p PIVOT (MAX(p.PivotValue) FOR PivotHeader IN (' + @pivotHeaders + ') ) AS ptable'
EXEC sp_executesql @psql
```

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. My mistake, i should add the data rather than picture. I am using SQL server 2012. I will check it today and let you know.

Comment: Thank you Kevin :-)